# Better solution to a ton of switch cases in command line game

Tags: c++, command-line, architecture, switch-statement, game-development

I’m currently writing a project in c++
to turn the book “Fighting Fantasy” into a command line game. For those of you who don’t know, Fighting Fantasy is an interactive novel game where you start on page one and based on decisions you make, you flip to different pages. For example, on page 1 “you arrive at a cave, flip to page 30 to go east, flip to page 40 to go west.”

Now the way I currently have this implemented is: I have all the mechanics of the game (items, stats, battles, etc.) abstracted into different files/functions and my main function serves as the control. I treat every page as an event, so for example, if the player goes east, then the event is set to 30. There’s a MASSIVE switch case inside a while loop that’s inside main, and each case calls the functions required to run the specific mechanics for that page, then sets the next event before it loops again.

Now, there are 400 events in this book, which means 400 cases. My question is, is it poor design to have that many cases? Or is it okay in this situation since it’s a very simple/logical way of navigating the book/story? Furthermore, if this really poor, what suggestions would you have for improving the logic flow for this game?

Thank you!

Comment: How about a *map* that maps the input to a specific "page"?

Comment: You will get opinion based answers. Not necessarily bad but very hard to maintain. Usually if you have a lot of something (400) try to split up the big problem into smaller ones. Do you really have 400 command, or are they split up in a lot less smaller (sub)commands? (Then consider std::map<case,std::function<void()> handler>)

Comment: Without actually seeing your code, I'd say yes: you appear to be describing something horrendous. The fact that _you_ are uncomfortable with it is a good indicator. If your game has a set of story-lines and basic decisions to move from one part to the next, it can loosely be represented as _directed graph_, if not a directed _acylclic_ graph. The entire thing could probably be represented as a simple text file, which you read into the graph and then execute with a simple function. You could then largely develop the story without modifying the program.

Comment: Choose-your-own-adventure games *(in their simplest form)* are a directed graph.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think that is the best advice possible

Comment: Regarding _actual_ mechanics, I doubt there's 400 unless you have hand-crafted each one to a specific scenario. But that would mean maybe you're handling the entire game logic in one place, which is too much responsibility. You probably interact with the player, other characters, and the environment. The game itself is almost surely comprised of world state, player state and scenes/environment. All those are connected by rules and driven by player actions. All this could be abstracted to a very simple language that defines the entire game in a way that's flexible and extensible.

Comment: *There’s a MASSIVE switch case inside a while loop* -- Here is the problem -- you knew that what you were doing was basically crazy when you wrote the first 10 or 20 case statements.  So what did you do?  You kept going with more case statements..   You should have stopped right there and said to yourself "there must be a better way".  Now it's gotten out-of-control and you have to redesign things.  Better to anticipate that a design is going out of control, stopping it and take a step back to reevaluate things.

Comment: Re: “each case calls the **functions**” — each case should call **one** function which, in turn, calls “the functions”. That way the entire `switch/case` logic is just boilerplate.

Comment: maybe a finite state machine. I doubt that the player is ever in a situation to choose between 400 differrent options. I suppose that rather the player can choose between a small number of actions depending on their current state and the action will take them to the next state

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number this is what I’m settling on. But I assume the only way to do this would to treat every page as a state, but then you would have 400 states, but at least in this situation there are only 2-3 states the player can move to at a time

Answer (score 1):

If all your program does is print the text content of a page and then perform an action afterwards, and if this action is either to

1. go to the next page, or
2. jump to a certain page number, or
3. ask the user a question and perform an action depending on the response, or
4. exit the program,

then you could assign a `struct action` to every page and to every possible choice of a question, and define `struct action` and `struct question` like this:

```
struct question;

struct action
{
    enum class types
    {
        GO_TO_NEXT_PAGE,
        JUMP_TO_PAGE,
        ASK_QUESTION,
        EXIT_PROGRAM
    } type;

    union
    {
        //this member is only valid when "type" is JUMP_TO_PAGE
        int target;

        //this member is only valid when "type" is ASK_QUESTION
        question *q;
    };
};

struct question
{
    const char* text;
    std::vector<action> actions;
};
```

That way, if you have an array of objects that each represent a page and if every such object contains a `struct action`, you will only need the program logic necessary to process these actions. You will be able to add pages to the game without the need of adding additional program logic.

Here is an example of a full working program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <exception>

struct question;

struct action
{
    enum class types
    {
        GO_TO_NEXT_PAGE,
        JUMP_TO_PAGE,
        ASK_QUESTION,
        EXIT_PROGRAM
    } type;

    union
    {
        //this member is only valid when "type" is JUMP_TO_PAGE
        int target;

        //this member is only valid when "type" is ASK_QUESTION
        question* q;
    };
};

struct question
{
    const char* text;
    std::vector<action> actions;
};

struct page
{
    const char* text;
    action a;
};

//this function initializes all game data and
//returns a pointer to the first page
page* init_game()
{
    //create questions
    static question questions[] =
    {
        //question 0
        {
            "Do you want to\n"
            "1. head west, or\n"
            "2. head east?\n"
            "Enter choice: ",
            {
                {
                    .type = action::types::GO_TO_NEXT_PAGE,
                    .target = -1
                },
                {
                    .type = action::types::JUMP_TO_PAGE,
                    .target = 2
                }
            }
        },

        //question 1
        {
            "Do you want to\n"
            "1. fight the ogre, or\n"
            "2. run away?\n"
            "Enter choice: ",
            {
                {
                    .type = action::types::GO_TO_NEXT_PAGE,
                    .target = -1
                },
                {
                    .type = action::types::JUMP_TO_PAGE,
                    .target = 4
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //create pages
    static page pages[] =
    {
        //NOTE: The page numbers printed by the game are
        //      1-based, whereas the page numbers inside
        //      the program's code are 0-based.

        //page 0
        {
            "You are in a forest. To the west, you see a\n"
            "river. To the east, you see an ogre.\n",
            {
                .type = action::types::ASK_QUESTION,
                .q = &questions[0]
            }
        },

        //page 1
        {
            "You reach the river. After drinking some water out\n"
            "of the river, you find nothing further of interest,\n"
            "so you head back east to the forest.\n",
            {
                .type = action::types::JUMP_TO_PAGE,
                .target = 0
            }
        },

        //page 2
        {
            "You are being attacked by an ogre.\n",
            {
                .type = action::types::ASK_QUESTION,
                .q = &questions[1]
            }
        },

        //page 3
        {
            "You hit the ogre with your sword and kill it.\n",
            {
                .type = action::types::EXIT_PROGRAM,
                .target = -1
            }
        },

        //page 4
        {
            "While you attempt to run away, the ogre\n"
            "throws its axe at you and it kills you.\n",
            {
                .type = action::types::EXIT_PROGRAM,
                .target = -1
            }
        }
    };

    return &pages[0];
}

void game_logic( page* pages )
{
    int page_num = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        //print the page content
        std::cout << "Page " << page_num + 1 << ":\n";
        std::cout << pages[page_num].text;

        //perform action(s) for the page
        action* a = &pages[page_num].a;
        for (;;)
        {
            switch ( a->type )
            {
                case action::types::GO_TO_NEXT_PAGE:
                    page_num++;
                    break;
                case action::types::JUMP_TO_PAGE:
                    page_num = a->target;
                    break;
                case action::types::ASK_QUESTION:
                {
                    int answer;

                    //print the question
                    std::cout << a->q->text;

                    //get response
                    std::cin >> answer;
                    if ( !std::cin )
                        throw std::runtime_error( "input error" );

                    //perform the next action                    
                    a = &a->q->actions.at(answer-1);
                    continue;
                }
                case action::types::EXIT_PROGRAM:
                    return;
                default:
                    throw std::runtime_error( "internal error" );
            }

            //add spacing
            std::cout << '\n';

            //we have completed all actions, so break out
            //of infinite loop
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    page* first = init_game();

    try
    {
        game_logic( first );
    }
    catch ( const std::exception &e )
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception occurred: " << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

This program has the following behavior:

```
Page 1:
You are in a forest. To the west, you see a
river. To the east, you see an ogre.
Do you want to
1. head west, or
2. head east?
Enter choice: 1

Page 2:
You reach the river. After drinking some water out
of the river, you find nothing further of interest,
so you head back east to the forest.

Page 1:
You are in a forest. To the west, you see a
river. To the east, you see an ogre.
Do you want to
1. head west, or
2. head east?
Enter choice: 2

Page 3:
You are being attacked by an ogre.
Do you want to
1. fight the ogre, or
2. run away?
Enter choice: 2

Page 5:
While you attempt to run away, the ogre
throws its axe at you and it kills you.
```

Ok, that didn't go well, so let's try a different choice:

```
Page 1:
You are in a forest. To the west, you see a
river. To the east, you see an ogre.
Do you want to
1. head west, or
2. head east?
Enter choice: 2

Page 3:
You are being attacked by an ogre.
Do you want to
1. fight the ogre, or
2. run away?
Enter choice: 1

Page 4:
You hit the ogre with your sword and kill it.
```